# How to count over 1,000,000 in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, numbering

I'm using After Effects CC and I want to count numbers over 2,000,000. There are two effects I tried to use:

1. "slider control" - the problem with this effect it has limit to 1,000,000 and I can't enter a higher value.
2. "numbers" - it has the same problem, it is limited to 30,000 and I can't enter a higher value .

What can I do to count over 1,000,000?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use a text layer with an expression to about 3,000,000.

Here's an example that count from 0 to 3,000,000 in 4 seconds:

```
startCount = 0;

endCount = 3000000;

countDur = 4;

Math.round(linear(time,0,countDur,startCount,endCount))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a post on [Creative Cow](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/227/16810), you can use the angle control.

I needed a number in the hundreds of millions, so I enter that as an angle value, and I then had to add one line expression to my text layer's source text value:

```
effect("Angle Control")("Angle")/360
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a point control instead of a slider which is not limited to 1,000,000
or you can use this Counter preset that does the same but faster:
http://www.vdodna.com/products/counter-preset/

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the slider. For example if you want to get to 2 000 000, then multiply it by 2.

[image]

Comment: As it stands this is a link only answer and will be deleted soon.  Please add in own words how to solve the given problem. Your given link can then be an additional information.  Suppose the link is broken your answer is completly useless ...  Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the point counter instead of multiplying it.

The point counter can go to 999 billion, same method with the pick whip tool like the slider but instead you're going to use the Point count effect.

The cool thing about this is you can keyframe it too so you can stop it if needs be.

Cheers,

Callum

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if you still need this but I managed to solve this problem recently:

https://youtu.be/5WJmrYMifW8

Comment: Please add a brief description of the method to your answer, rather than just providing link. Link only answers are likely to be deleted.